# Using app.config both for WCF service/client configuration and for application-specific settings

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configurationmanager

When I develop a WCF service/client with a configuration file, a new file `app.config` is created with a section `system.serviceModel`. Since in my application I should save and load *application-specific settings* (colors, location of log files, etc), I read documentation about [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class: these settings are also stored in the `app.config` file within the *appSettings* section.
So, the configuration parameters both for the WCF service/client and for the application-specific settings are loaded from the same file `app.config`, but from different sections.

Is this the type of use of the `app.config` file?
Or should I use a different file for the application-specific settings?
Moreover I did not understand the use of configSections...

Comment: Do you want users to be able to modify the system.serviceModel section on the client?

Comment: Maybe so in the future, but now my doubts were about the scope of use of `app.config`.

Comment: For the client side at least, I prefer to do all service configuration in code. A user could really mess things up by modifying the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you describe is exactly how the app.config file works.

Normally there are different parts in app.config file for things like Connection Strings, WCF configuration settings but also for your own custom settings.

The [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class can be used to access Application specific settings, Connection strings and other configuration data.

ConfigSections are defined on your machine for all standard configuration elements. You can also use ConfigSections to create your own custom sections that can be placed in app.config.

[Here is some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) how to do that.